# Prove/disprove that two closed sets are equal iff they share the same boundary and one is a subset of the other.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I have two sets in $\mathbb R^n$ that share a boundary , and I know, by definition, that one is a subset of the other. How do I prove that both sets are the same? And if it isn't necessarily true, how do I prove otherwise?
Edit: The two sets share some points not on the boundary and the superset is the closure of a ball, if this information is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the last edit of the question $B$ is a ball and $A\subset B$ a closed set having the same boundary as $B$ and containing at least one point $x$ in the interior of $B\,.$

***Claim.*** $A=B\,.$

Proof. Assume there exists $y\in B\setminus A\,.$ Since $x,y\in B$ and $B$ is convex
the entire line segment connecting $x$ and $y$ is in $B\,.$ (This is the very definition of convexity of a set.) It is clear that $y$ cannot be in the boundary of $B$ or the boundary of $A$ but on the line segment connecting $x$ and $y$ there must exist a $z$ that is on the boundary of $A$ (continuity & mean value theorem). Since $x,y$ are in the interior of $B$ so is $z$ ($z$ is not an extremal point, and only the boundary points of $B$ are extremal points). This means we found $z\in\partial A\setminus\partial B$ which is a contradiction to the assumption $\partial A=\partial B\,.$

Answer (score 3):

What about $B=\partial A$ with empty interior, e.g in $\mathbb R^2$ the disk and the circle.

Because $A$ is closed it contains its boundary, so $B$ is a subset of $A$ sharing the same boundary, yet not necessarily equal.

[image]

I see where you want to lead to with the question in your comment (i.e. what if $A$ and $B$ have common points inside the disk), but it is more complicated than that.

Consider the figure  above, $A$ on the left, $B$ on the right. They have the same boundary in black, $B$ subset of $A$, have two petals of non-empty interior in common, yet they are not equal.

Comment: What if the two sets shared some elements not in the boundary?

Comment: Good question, I posted an addendum.

Comment: Thank you. But I have another question, under what extra circumstances would the sets be equal. This proof is part of a bigger proof and I am confident that the counter examples don't hold there. I edited the question as well to account for the details I should have put there.

Comment: An additional convexity argument (for $A$,$B$ ?) would probably eliminate cases like the second one (not the first one, as half-plane and line works) but this is a very strong constraint. At this point this is a case by case situation, where the original problem matters. I'm not too sure about further generalisations.

Comment: I am unsure of how to go about the convexity argument. I am still new to topology. Can you give some advice? Specifically, what properties of convex sets should I use? Also, can you direct me to good books on the topic? I'm pretty much taught by YouTube videos.

Comment: @Vector . I tried to give an answer that shows which topics about convex sets you need to study. Google the buzz words and try at least Wikipedia rather than YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the original question.  (It has now been added that the space is $\mathbb R^n$.)

If topological space $X$ is not connected, we could have subsets  $A \subset B=X$ where $A$ is clopen (hence $A$ and $B$ both have empty boundary).

Comment: The topological space is connected.

Comment: B is the closure of a ball; it has a non-empty boundary.