# Help with a proof about a set that is a convex cone

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis

I have a question about the proof of a theorem.

If $E$ is a vector space.

$\bullet$ The line segment with endpoints $u,v$ is by definition the set $\left [ u,v \right ]= (1-t)u+tv:0\leq t\leq 1$

$\bullet$ $X\subset{E}$ is convex $\Leftrightarrow $ $(u,v\in X\Rightarrow \left [ u,v \right ]\subset X) $.

$\bullet$ $C\subset{E}$ is a cone $\Leftrightarrow $ $(u\in C\wedge t>0\Rightarrow tu\in C) $

The theorem is as follows:

Let $C\subset E $ be a cone.

$C$ is a convex set $\Leftrightarrow (u,v\in C\Rightarrow u+v\in C )$

$$Proof$$

$( \Rightarrow) $

$u,v\in C\Rightarrow (1-t)u+tv\in C $ for all $t\in\left [ 0,1 \right ]$ (since $C$ is convex)

$\Rightarrow (1-\frac{1}{2})u+\frac{1}{2}v\in C $ (taking $t=\frac{1}{2}$)

$\Rightarrow 2\left ( \frac{1}{2}u+\frac{1}{2}v\right )=u+v\in C  $ (since $C$ is a cone)

$(\Leftarrow) $

$u\in C \wedge (1-t)>0\Rightarrow (1-t)u\in C$

$v\in C \wedge t>0\Rightarrow tv\in C$

(the above because $C$ is a cone)

$u,v\in C \Rightarrow (1-t)u \in C \wedge tv\in C $ for all $t\in \left \langle 0,1 \right \rangle$ (here I have a doubt if what I inferred from $u,v\in C$ is correct)

$\Rightarrow (1-t)u+tv\in C $ for all $t\in \left \langle 0,1 \right \rangle$ (if the above were true, we could add the two vectors and they would belong to $C$, we have this new vector that belongs to $C$ but $t$ is in an open interval and not closed as the definition of a convex set says)

Perhaps there is another way to prove the theorem.
My doubt is about the return of the proof.
Thank you!!!

Comment: Your proof is correct. You already  prove if $C$ is cone and $\forall u, v\in C$, $(1-t)u+tv\in C$ for $t\in (0,1)$. Since $u, v$ already belong to $C$, thus $\forall u, v\in C$, $(1-t)u+tv\in C$ for $t\in [0,1]$.

Comment: Use your words, proofs with mostly symbols are hard to decipher. For the $(\Leftarrow)$ I would write something like: Suppose $u,v \in C$ and $t\in (0,1)$, then $(1-t) u \in C, t v \in C$ and so $(1-t)u+tv \in C$ hence $C$ is convex.

Comment: For C to be convex it would not have to be that t $ \in $ [0,1]?

Comment: For $C$ to be convex you can assume that $t$ is in the open interval because you start with $u,v\in C$ so that the cases $t=0$ and $t=1$ are trivial. Regarding ***copper.hat's comment***. I could not agree more. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4824359/949989) is an example of a proof that uses as few logical symbols as possible and as many words as possible.

Comment: I had the impression that using more symbols in a mathematical proof was better.

For example, in the proof's return, I wanted to precisely arrive from here $u,v\in C$  to  $(1-t)u+tv \in C$ for all  $0\leq t\leq 1$.

I have another question: can I use this definition of convex set?

$C$ is convex $\Leftrightarrow $  $u,v\in C\Rightarrow (1-t)u+tv \in C $ for all $0< t<1$ 

in place of this

$C$ is convex $\Leftrightarrow $  $ u,v\in C\Rightarrow (1-t)u+tv \in C $ for all $0\leq t\leq 1$